# Tomcat 8 - Statementcache settings

Tags: tomcat, caching, jdbc

I'm trying to understand how the statementcache setting in Tomcat 8 changes application behavior.

For example, one of our deployed applications has some data randomly change languages as users click around on the site.

Vendor is suggesting changing the statementcache setting to zero to hopefully resolve the issue. They believe the individual user's browser language setting is causing this problem. User A has Arabic setup on their browser, they use site, log out. User B (with English setting) logs on and uses website, some data shows up in Arabic, some in English...

I'm looking for some advise on this issue as I am not sure how to reliably test this setting change outside of our production environment to make sure this fixes the issue/doesn't introduce other problems.

Thanks!

Comment: What statement cache are you taking about?

Comment: I don't think it's the fault of the [StatementCache](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementCache) which stores the statements only, not the query results. Do you have an application level cache with a scope broader than user session?